# URL-Encode javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to url-encode...How do I this? this syntax is wrong ...

Here is my code:

```
   <div class="post-btn-share">
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
    <div class="float-all">
        <script>
            var url = urlencode('http://mypage.com/visualizar_foto.php?img=55&user=2&xx=');
            alert(url);
            </script>
        <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=" + url + "&send=true&layout=standard&width=300&show_faces=true&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=80" frameborder="0" style="border:none;" scrolling="no" width="320" height="240"></iframe>
        <div class="float-all">

        </div>
        <div class="float-all">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You cannot type JavaScript code at random spots and make it work. You need to use `<script>` tags and/or certain HTML attributes (but not all of them, only those that are designed to hold JavaScript!). You need to use the JavaScript console. You need to learn the basics. I'm voting to close because this question is not going to help anyone else (which is the ultimate goal of the site).

Answer (score 2):

Try with :

```
var url = encodeURIComponent('http://mypage.comvisualizar_foto.php?img=55&user=2&xx=');
```

Comment: and how I use this url in my iframe...is right what I did?

Comment: @illDev - What you did is wrong at several levels. You are using a function that does not exist and you don't make any difference between JavaScript and HTML. You're apparently not even using any developer tool.

Comment: I need set the url encoded in    **  <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=" + url + "&send=true&layout=standard&width=300&show_faces=true&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=80" frameborder="0" style="border:none;" scrolling="no" width="320" height="240"></iframe> ** how?

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode('http://mypage.com/visualizar_foto.php?img=55&user=2&xx='); ?>&send=true&layout=standard&width=300&show_faces=true&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=80" frameborder="0" style="border:none;" scrolling="no" width="320" height="240"></iframe>
```

Comment: it's right or no? why downvote?